# Is it true that if $(X,\tau)$ is metrizable then it is a locally compact space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Let's say $(X,\tau)$ is locally compact if every $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact. Now if $(X,\tau)$ is metrizable then it is a locally compact space.

I'm not sure of the above claim. The reason I claim it to be true is that if the space is metrizable we have open balls of arbitrary radii about the points of $X$ from which we can elicit a closed ball containing the point which indeed is compact. This seems very trivial. But is my reasoning alright? Or are there any counter-examples?

Thanks.

***Added later:*** (@Lord Shark the Unknown)
Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $(\mathbb{Q},\tau_{Euc})$ is locally compact. Let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $q$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{U\cap \mathbb{Q}}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ and $\overline{U\cap\mathbb{Q}}$ is compact. But $\overline{U\cap\mathbb{Q}}\cap(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})\neq\emptyset$ as $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$; hence we have a contradiction.

Is what you are saying true because of this?

Comment: There's no reason to use $q\in\mathbb R$ - the topology on $\mathbb Q$ has neighborhoods of points $q\in\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rationals $\Bbb Q$ under the usual metric is not locally compact.

Comment: Could you please check the added later part in my question?

Comment: @Janitha357 This is basically the case. Any compact subset of $\Bbb Q$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ and so is closed in $\Bbb R$. If it contains a nontrivial interval in $\Bbb Q$ then that contains an irrational limit point so the set can't be closed in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The added part is logically incorrect.  If  $Q$ were locally compact then $q $ would have a nbhd $U$ in R such that$ Cl_Q(U\cap Q)=Q\cap Cl_R(U\cap Q)$  is compact.  The fact that $Q$ is dense in $R $is not by itself sufficient to obtain a contradiction. For example if the topology on a set $X$ is $\{X,\phi\}$  then any non-empty subspace of $X $is dense in $X$ and is compact. More specific properties of $Q$ and $R$ need to be used.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I considered $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  The closures are taken with respect to $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{Euc})$. I agree that I should have mentioned it and it is illogical\a mistake to skip it.

Answer (score 4):

Local compactness is a pretty heavy condition fot a topological space, and fairly unrelated to metrizibility.

For example, any subspace of a metrizable space is again metrizable, a property which is nog at all true for local compactness.

Another example is from Functional Analysis: any normed space is clearly metrizable, but if it is locally compact then its dimension is necessarily finite!

Comment: I really like the example from functional analysis!

Answer (score 1):

To see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact: note that if we have any set of the form $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, it has a sequence $(q_n)$ converging to some $p \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and this shows that $\overline{(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}}$ (closure taken in $\mathbb{Q}$) is not sequentially compact. And sets of this form are a base of the rationals.

Comment: Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $(\mathbb{Q},\tau_{Euc})$ is locally compact. Let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $q$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{U\cap \mathbb{Q}}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ and $\overline{U\cap\mathbb{Q}}$ is compact. But $\overline{U\cap\mathbb{Q}}\cap(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})\neq\emptyset$ as $\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$; hence we have a contradiction. Here $(\mathbb{Q},\tau_{Euc})$ is taken as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and the closures are taken with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. Is this argument flawed?